# How do i get bin or wwwroot directory in ASP.NET MVC 6 (SIX) code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC 5 I used

```
_myStem = new MyStemWrapper(Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "mystem.exe"));
```

to get path to file.

In ASP.NET MVC 6 I can't get path by the same way. I need to get path before any requests since my wrapper is a singleton created by IOC

```
var d = AppDomain.CurrentDomain; // some path to C:\Users\username\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta5\bin
var r = HttpRuntime.BinDirectory; // ArgumentNullException
var r2 = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath; // ArgumentNullException
var ap = Apllication.StartupPath; // Application class missing
var s = Server.MapPath("~/") // Server class missing
```

Comment: You can use `IApplicationEnviroment`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ASP.NET 5 you can easily access these information using `IApplicationEnvironment`:

```
private readonly IApplicationEnvironment _app;
public HomeController(IApplicationEnvironment app)
{
   _app = app;
}
public IActionResult Index()
{
   var path = _app.ApplicationBasePath;
}
```

**Update**: If you want exactly the wwwroot path, You can inject `IHostingEnvironment` and get `WebRootPath` property:

```
private readonly IHostingEnvironment _app;
public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment app)
{
     _app = app;
}
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var path = _app.WebRootPath;
}
```